# my code ruins file name

Tags: php, regex

how can i preserve the dots in a file name while grabbing its extension?
i am exploding the string to grab the file extension but then all the dots inside the filename disappears as well.

```
    $description = '';
    $file = "Another Magazine. photos by joe smith. girl_brunette_headband.jpg";
    $file = explode('.',$file);
    $extension = end($file);

    $num_rows = count($file);
    $j=0;
    while($j<=$num_rows){
        $description .= $file[$j];
        $description = preg_replace("/$extension/", '', $description);
        $j++;
    }

    echo $description;// outputs:  Another Magazine photos by joe smith girl_brunette_headband
```

what i want output is: Another Magazine. photos by joe smith. girl_brunette_headband

Comment: Another case to consider: `gift.gif`. With your current code, it will return `t`.

Comment: it is not explode ruins filename, you know.

Comment: if not explode,  then what is erasing the dots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the *filename* (that is the *basename* w/o the *extension*), you can use the [`pathinfo`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/pathinfo) function:

```
$description = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

To get the extension, it's similar:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

ehm
`echo substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '.'));`

Comment: It doesn't not give the extension. Rather the file name.

Comment: quoting:
>
>what i want output is: Another Magazine. photos by joe smith. > girl_brunette_headband